# UITextView autocorrect on a text with abnormal behavior iPhone X

Tags: swift, uitextview

I have UITextView with typing attributes for font, and paragraph spacing. I have no clue how to explain this error. This works fine on all iPhones except iPhone X.

[image]

Comment: as I know there was an autocorrect bug in 11.1 so which iOS version are you using

Comment: ya.. but that bug was fixing "i" from "A?"